# how to log all coming messages of SSH Secure Shell client?

Tags: security, ssh

I am using SSH Secure Shell client, a nice tool to connect to the server.

However, I am wondering whether is it possible to log all of coming messages from my program that I run via the SSH Secure Shell client. for example: ./test and my program will run with giving debug lines. how can I log the debug lines to a txt file for analysing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tryed?

```
./test > log.txt
```

Comment: if you need to grab anything off stderr (not sure if that even makes sense), then you can use ./test &> log.txt